# Creating a border on last table row of a dynamic created table via php out of a database

Tags: php, html, css, sql, database

Good evening,

I'm trying to find a function, where I can border the last table row from a dynamic created table.

```
<?php
session_start( );
echo '<br><br><br><h1 class="HLast">Your last order</h1>';

    if( isset( $_SESSION['oldSession']) === true ){
        $price = 0;
        $resultsetOldOrder = $dbr->query( ' SELECT sn.preis, sn.name from food_order fo, speisen_neu sn 
                                            where fo.SID = "'.$_SESSION['oldSession'].'"
                                            and sn.Artikelnummer = fo.artikelnummer ' );


        if( $resultsetOldOrder == true){
            echo '<table class="LastText">';
            foreach( $resultsetOldOrder as $row ){
                echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['preis'].'</td></tr>';
                $price = $price + $row['preis'];

            }
            echo '<tr><td>Total</td><td>'.$price.'</td></tr></table>
                <table class="LastButton"><tr><td><form action = "printBill.php" method = "post">
                <input type = "hidden" name = "oldOderID" value ="'.$_SESSION['oldSession'].'">
                <button type = "submit">Print bill</button></form></tr></table>';

        }else{
            echo 'You have no last order';
        }
    }

?>
```

This one up here is my code. It works fine. 
In a normal table i would simply try to give the last td a class and set a border around. But this is not possible here and I can't find anything in the web aswell.

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while there's a better way to do this with css, to do this without making much changes to your codes, you can count the total number of rows in `$resultsetOldOrder` and then check within the loop if the current row is the last one.

```
    if( $resultsetOldOrder == true){
        $last_index = count($resultsetOldOrder) - 1;
        echo '<table class="LastText">';
        foreach( $resultsetOldOrder as $index => $row ){
            if($index == $last_index) {
                //This is the last row, do whatever you want
            }
            echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['preis'].'</td></tr>';
            $price = $price + $row['preis'];

        }
        echo '<tr><td>Total</td><td>'.$price.'</td></tr></table>
            <table class="LastButton"><tr><td><form action = "printBill.php" method = "post">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "oldOderID" value ="'.$_SESSION['oldSession'].'">
            <button type = "submit">Print bill</button></form></tr></table>';

    }else{
        echo 'You have no last order';
    }
```

Of course this is assuming `$resultsetOldOrder` array is indexed 0 to x. If its not, you can set `$i = 0` before the loop and check inside the loop if `$i == $last_index` then do `$i++`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS you can select the last element of a type.
Take a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/).
So in your case, you would do

```
tr:last-of-type {
    //your styles here
}
```